# Stop script in dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

at the moment I am working on replacing pop-up on a website I inherited. Those pop-ups used modal dialogs, which are on their way out and even were dropped by pop-up blockers on client side.

My approach was loading the HTML of the pop-up into an div on the main site, while hiding the original content, then emptying the div and switch the main content back to visible.

This works so fa, but the loaded content has scripts that run to check if someone is already using that function. The first time you use that function all is fine. The script runs, sees noone is using the function, I go through the stuff, empty the div and return to the main content. When trying to use the function a second time the script to still run (console shows the requests), even though I emptied the div, prompting the eternal "please wait till other user is finished" lines, since the first script is still checking for use, signalling the second script "I'm buisy".

So right now, I am looking for a way to stop the first script, since removing the HTML-content doesn't suffice it seems.

The code so far:

```
$("#dialog").load("stuffToLoad.htm",function(response, status)
{
   if(status=="success"){
      $(".fullTable").toggle();
      $("#dialog").toggle();
   };
})
```

to get the content. The in-use-check is done with a post-request, that is repeated by a `window.setTimeout` every second. That part seems to still run.

When everything is done, or the user runs into an error I tried:

```
      function returnToProcVal()
      {
         $("#dialog").html("");
        $("#dialog").toggle();
        $(".fullTable").toggle();
     }
```

to delete the function content and scripts, to stop them running. While the DOM says all is gone I can see the post requests being repeated in the console.

I'd be grateful for any pointer or perhaps even better methods to get the function running and returning the user, without the use of pop-ups.

Comment: If you are using `window.setTimeout` to perform regular pings/calls when the modal box is opened, you will have to use `window.clearTimeout` when you close the modal box to ensure that it is no longer making post requests.

Comment: Yup, it was that simple. Since it was a seperate pop-up-window before this wasn't needed. Now everythign is fine. If you'd post it as an answer I could mark it as the correct one. Even though I wonder why the connection and script is kept open, even though the content, including the script, is removed from the page.